# SqlDataReader.ReadAsync stuck on huge blob

Tags: c#, async-await, sqldatareader

Have a look at this code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("some connection string"))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select document from myTable where id = 'xyz'", connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {

                if (await reader.ReadAsync())

                    if (!await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0))
                    {
                        data = reader.GetStream(0);
                    }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Document is an image field on my SQL Database, and it can get huge. While it is working fine with small blobs (tested with 200 kB Blobs), it is not working with huge blobs (currently testing with a 400 MB Blob).
When I use the debugger and step through the code, I see that it enters the line with await reader.ReadAsync() and there we stay forever.

However in the following cases it worked as expected:

- just call reader.Read() (instead of ReadAsync)
- or when I call ExecuteReaderAsync with: CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess

But why doesn't it work with Non-SequentialAccess without even throwing any error?

What I get is this callstack on the Threads-Window:
[image]

Just realized that this callstack changes over time, so there seems something in progress:
[image]

But however, it does not come to an end.

Comment: Is any callers higher up the call stack doing `.Result` or `.Wait()` instead of a `await`? If you put `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on each `await` in your code does the problem go away?

Comment: The code is not more then you see. It is just an empty windows forms project and a button which is calling the code in the example. I faced this issue in a bigger project and created this simple application to verify it. ConfigureAwait(false) doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you update the question showing the code in the calling button and the method signature of the current method? Also showing how you did the ConfigureAwait would be useful too.

Comment: I updated it. It is just the button_click event that is calling the sql reading code. Not more then that. - Actually I faced the same issue in a much bigger vb.net project in a web-api controller. It seems to be related to the size of the blob.

Comment: If you had not said `reader.Read()` I would have suspected you just needed to wait longer for the read to finish, but honestly I am now stumped. The reason `SequentialAccess` works is when you are in that mode `Read/ReadAsync()` only reads the header info and returns, when not in the mode it must fully read the whole row in to memory before returning. See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx) for a more indepth description.

Comment: Yeah...me too. reader.read() just works and it takes a few seconds. Also nothing seems to happen with reader.ReadAsync() at all. I don't see any memory footprint or something else happening.

Comment: Yeah...unfortunately, for now I need to read it in total. So SequentialAccess is not an option

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the callstack one WorkerThread...don't know if this is of any help